# When invoking an assignment of a method to itself, why is `this` undefined?

Tags: javascript, this, dynamic-scope

This code defines an object `bar` and calls the function `foo` in various ways:

```js
"use strict";

function foo() {
  return this;
}

let bar = {
  foo,
  baz() {
    return this;
  }
};

console.log( foo() ); // undefined (or globalThis outside strict mode)

console.log( bar.foo() ); // bar
console.log( (bar.foo)() ); // bar

console.log( (bar.foo = bar.foo)() ); // undefined (or globalThis outside strict mode)
```

Can someone please help me understand why `(bar.foo = bar.foo)()` is `undefined`?

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Would you please add this as an answer, would be more useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function, there’s a special thing that happens in JavaScript engines; it’s a behavior that can be found in the specification and it is what allows the `this` value to be automatically bound in a method call.

ECMAScript defines the syntax `bar.baz.foo()` as a [*CallMemberExpression*](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-CallMemberExpression).

```js
   bar.baz.foo();
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  CallMemberExpression
// ^^^^^^^^^^^    ├─ MemberExpression
// ^^^^^^^        │  ├─ MemberExpression
//         ^^^    │  └─ IdentifierName
//            ^^  └─ Arguments
```

The way that this is [evaluated](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation) involves splitting the *CallMemberExpression* into its constituent *MemberExpression* and *Arguments*.
Then, the [*MemberExpression*](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-MemberExpression) is [evaluated](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation) which splits it into its constituent *MemberExpression* and *IdentifierName*.
The *MemberExpression*s are all recursively processed, and [evaluated](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getvalue) as a single value of a *language type* (i.e. one of the familiar JavaScript types, usually the Object type).

In the end, a value of a so-called *specification type* is generated: namely a [Reference Record](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-reference-record-specification-type).
These Reference Records are key–value pairs with four properties, but the relevant ones are `[[Base]]` and `[[ReferencedName]]`.
The `[[Base]]` property contains the value of `bar.baz` (the evaluated nested *MemberExpression*), and the `[[ReferencedName]]` is the string `"foo"` (the string value of the *IdentifierName*).
*This* is what the function call proceeds with.

The [specification types](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-specification-types) are distinct from the [language types](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types).
Values of specification types are never observable in the language itself, and they might not actually exist.
Specification types only “exist” to help explain concepts in the specification, but an implementation is free to choose whatever representation is suitable, as long as its behavior is equivalent to the normative specification text.

The last step of the function call evaluation says “Return ? [EvaluateCall](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-evaluatecall)(*func*, *ref*, *arguments*, *tailCall*)”, where *func* is the function object (of the *language type* Object) `bar.baz.foo` and *ref* is the Reference Record { [[Base]]: `bar.baz`, [[ReferencedName]]: `"foo"` }.
And the last step of EvaluateCall says: “Return ? [Call](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-call)(*func*, *thisValue*, *argList*)”.
When the function call is finally initiated here, it receives the function object to be invoked (*func*), the value for `this` (*thisValue*) which comes directly from the [[Base]] property of the Reference Record (except in a few special cases), and the *argList* from the *Arguments*.
This looks very close to `func.call(thisValue, ...argList)` in JavaScript, where `func === bar.baz.foo` and `thisValue === bar.baz`.

I hope, this visualization is of some use:

```js
   bar.baz.foo();
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  CallMemberExpression
// ^^^^^^^^^^^    ├─ MemberExpression ────────────────────┐
// ^^^^^^^        │  ├─ MemberExpression ─┐           (as object)
//         ^^^    │  └─ IdentifierName ─┐ │               │                 ┌─────────────────────┐
//            ^^  └─ Arguments ─┐       │ │ EvaluateCall( func, ref,        arguments, tailCall ) │
//                              │       │ │               │     │           └───┐                 │
//                              │       │ │         Call( func, │    thisValue, argList )         │
//                              │       │ │     ┌───────────────┘    │                            │
//                              │       │ │     Reference Record { [[Base]], [[ReferencedName]] } │
//                              │       │ │                          │         │                  │
//                              │       │ │                   (as object)  (as string)            │
//                              │       │ └──────────────────────────┘         │                  │
//                              │       └──────────────────────────────────────┘                  │
//                              └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But the expressions `bar.foo()`, `(bar.foo)()`, and similar ones like `bar.baz.foo()`, `(((bar.foo)))()`, etc. are *special* because they uniquely keep the Reference Record for the function call.
Almost all other expressions such as `(bar.foo = bar.foo)()`, `(0, bar.foo)()`, `(null ?? bar.foo)()`, etc. do *not*.
This comes mostly from the fact that they’re simply evaluated differently; in other words: JavaScript just works this way because the spec says so.

While theoretically possible to rewrite the spec and redesign the language such that `(0, bar.foo)()` or `const foo = bar.foo;` would keep the Reference Record or something similar (see Python with its bound methods), this would come with a *huge* compatibility impact, so we can’t really change the behavior.
I think this behavior was chosen because JavaScript was originally designed to be a *simple, easy to understand* language, and the contextual distinction between `const foo = (0, bar.foo);` producing a value of a language type, but `(0, bar.foo)()` keeping a value of a specification type, was too complicated for the early purpose of JavaScript as a language for the Web.

And even in the case of variable assignment, you lose the Reference Record, because you will be able to *observe* the assigned value, so it *has* to be of a language type:

```js
const foo1 = bar.foo; // Value `bar.foo` is observable by logging `foo1`.

console.log(foo1); // A function object.
                   // You will never see ReferenceRecord { [[Base]]: bar, [[ReferencedName]]: "foo" } here, because this doesn’t exist in the language.
```

Note that passing something as an argument or returning something from a function also counts as an *assignment*.

```js
const backcaller = (callback) => {
    // `callback` is a function object, not a Reference Record.
    callback();

    return callback;
  };

backcaller(bar.foo)   // A return value must be a language type, so this is a function object, not a Reference Record.
                   ()
```

See also:

- [How does the `this` keyword work, and when should it be used?](/q/3127429/4642212)
- [Losing `this` context when passing around members](/q/30486345/4642212)
- [What does this syntax mean? `(0, _parseKey2.default)(something)`](/q/35522560/4642212)

---

With the general explanation done, now let’s address some specific concerns of your question:

- The expression `bar.foo = bar.foo` [*returns* a value](/q/16027247/4642212); that value is the function object at `bar.foo`.
  Specifically, it must be a value of a *language type*, so it cannot be a Reference Record.
  The [specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-AssignmentExpression) says “Let *rval* be ? GetValue(*rref*)”, followed by “Return *rval*”.
  In simplified terms, GetValue either returns a value of a language type or throws a `ReferenceError`.
- `(bar.foo)()` is the same as `bar.foo()`.
  From [the huge `this` answer](/a/3127440/4642212):

  > This is explained in [this 2ality article](//2ality.com/2015/12/references.html) ([archived](//web.archive.org/web/20210201161804/https://2ality.com/2015/12/references.html)).
  > Particularly see [how a *ParenthesizedExpression* is evaluated](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-grouping-operator).

  The runtime semantics only have one step and a note:

  > ParenthesizedExpression : `(` Expression `)`
  >
  > 1. Return ? Evaluation of Expression. This may be of type Reference.
  >
  > #### Note
  >
  > This algorithm does not apply GetValue to Evaluation of Expression. The principal motivation for this is so that operators such as `delete` and `typeof` may be applied to parenthesized expressions.

  Sure enough, `delete` and `typeof` *need* to be able to accept a Reference Record, so they’re also “special” in the same way.